# Using the 6x13 font in web development

Tags: fonts, html, css

So, I'm making a game in the browser, and I want it too have a xterm-*like* feel.

However, I can't seem too get the included bdf's too work with CSS.
Will this font work? Or is there something like it that I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web browsers do not support the BDF format for fonts. You need to convert the font to other formats, such as TTF, using e.g. [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/).